# How can I make creating a PDFs collaboratively easier?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

Files are often send around to coworkers as PDFs as the can be read everywhere. How can doing this be made easier?

Comment: @Bioern Michaelsen:  I realise my answer below may be overkill, not knowing the size of your company or the volumes of documents you are processing, but if you are working in a non-regulated environment and you are looking for something really simple  sharing documents on Ubuntu One (Cloud repository) is probably the best way to go (using the shared folder functionality).

Comment: Some questions about your requirements.  Do you need to track who has read what document? Do you need to route the documents in a specific order?  Do you need to track and approve what changes have been made and by whom?

Answer (score 2):

## Alfresco

**Is an opensource alternative to Microsoft sharepoint**

Here are some of its important functions and features

1) **Managing documents:** Enable your business to create, capture, share and retain the content. From a single repository the company can manage documents, images, audio and video files. The files can also be previewed in the browser without the need to download them.

2) **Managing the records:** The records management feature of Alfresco helps file the records by using drag and drop feature from the desktop, email client, or any browser. It is developed on Alfresco’s document management repository. The users can choose appropriate interface for adding the records.

3) **Web content management:** Not exactly what you are asking for but this feature enables the web content developers to create the content, collaborate on the content, approve the content and finally publish it. It provides environment for the web teams to work together and collaborate.

4) **Enterprise collaboration:** Alfresco provides the platform for a number of teams spread across various parts of the country or the world to collaborate together on content or projects in a real-time manner. It has some powerful team tools like document library, Wiki, calendar and others. There are personal dashboards that allow the users to setup and view information anyway they want. The latest version of Alfresco provides excellent features for social content management.

[For more information click here](http://www.alfresco.com/)

Note: I have never used Alfresco, my company uses MS SharePoint but I have heard a lot a good things about it

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid PDFs are an excellent way to make this easier: 
http://webmink.com/2012/05/07/making-hybrid-pdfs/

It allows you to send people attachments you can be sure they can view, but which can also be edited with free, open source software.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use **Use Google Docs.**

It has one central document repoistory with the ability to export PDFs

You can also share a document with others for easy collaboration.